# HP CM2320 MFP can print but not scan

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10, the printer will print but not scan. Here is what we have tried.

1. Run Windows Update & restart the computer.
2. Remove existing imaging drivers via the Device Manager.
3. Remove existing printer drivers via the Device Manager.
4. Remove existing printers via Devices & Printers.
5. Then, download the [HP Color LaserJet CM2320 MFP Series Full Solution for Windows 10 32-bit](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3597359&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4191) from the HP Website.
6. Run that download to uninstall all components.
7. Restart CPU.
8. Run the download again to install the software.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to uninstall and reinstall all the device's drivers.

Comment: How is that different from what you tried in the steps listed in the question?

Comment: @Bob Good point. It isn't any different.

Answer (score 1):

First uninstalled the HP software on your computer.

Once this is done download the HP Color LaserJet CM2320 MFT Series Full Solution for Windows 10 32 or 64 bit which ever your computer is running.

I saved the file to my Desktop.

Then go to the internet icon in your system tray (bottom right hand corner of your screen, and right click on the icon.  This will give you a list of internet options, and identify the option you are currently connected too.
Click on the Disconnect button.

Now double click on the HP download on your desktop.  The print drivers will download to your computer.  You'll end up with an error message at the end. Close it and you'll see the drives were installed, and the fax and scan option are available for use as well as printing.

Best regards.

Comment: You did notice that the OP had already provided the solution for this (although the solution is really something he claimed already have done), right?

Comment: The difference was disconnecting from the internet before the install process.  If, you do not disconnect from the internet Windows 10 attempts in install the drivers from the windows drivers instead of installing the drivers in the hp install exe file!

Comment: Ok, fair enough. You should probably add that explanation to your answer, too (by [editing](http://superuser.com/posts/1110468/edit) it).

Comment: Zagrimsan, the fourth paragraph identifies disconnecting from the Internet before installing the HP install exe file.  You just didn't read my steps closely enough. - J. Orne

Comment: And you didn't understand me. What I suggest is that you add the reasoning why to disconnect from network into the answer. Otherwise it seems like an irrational extra step.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions online don't work, especially for older LaserJet MFP printers like the m475dw.  To Scan from desktop or from printer keypad Windows 10 fix:   You have to:  1) Select - Windows Services (Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services).  2) Select - Windows Image Acquisition (WIA).  3) Make sure it's running and set to run Automatic.  4) Select - Properties;  5)  Select - Logon tab and then Select - Local System Account and check: Allow service to interact with the desktop.   6) Select - login with your account and change from default to your main administrator's profile and logon password.
This will allow you to scan FROM THE DESKTOP software over WIFI or USB.  To then also scan from the printer keypad to a network folder you will have to turn on SMB v1.  For steps, Google search:  how to turn on windows 10 smbv1.  However, you should also Google the resulting security issues with turning it on, Google search:  security issues with smb v1.